# quick fix on IF - ELSE statment

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I've added an else statment in this code, but the result is showing multiple times the result after the `else`. The output is like: "No funds available  No funds available  No funds available  No funds available..."

```
    <div class="ddleft">{section name=p loop=$ps}
   {if $ps[p].balance > 0 and $ps[p].status == 1}
     <input type=radio name=type value="account_{$ps[p].id}">
     Deposit from Account Balance 
   {else}
     No funds available

   {/if}
{/section}</div>
```

Comment: You have a loop (loop=$ps) so I assume that array has more than one element.

Comment: What syntax is that?  Did I miss something or that is not PHP?

Comment: It's php, I think it uses the Smarty PHP Template Engine. https://www.smarty.net/